# How to do this assignment in C? Part 2

Tags: c, terminate

The following prompts input for the radius and height, and uses those values to calculate the volume of a cylinder. How can I  write this program so that it doesn't terminate when the user inputs a negative value for either radius of height? The range has to be 1-10 inclusive and no other prompts are allowed. The loop must be terminated only when something non-numeric is entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


float areaCirc(float r){
return (M_PI*r*r);
}

float volCyl(float r, float h){
return (areaCirc(r)*h);
}


int main(void) {
float r, h;
int k = 0;
float volume;
float avgh = 0;
float toth = 0;

do{
    float exit = scanf("%f%f", &r, &h);
    if (exit == 0) 
    {break;}
    if(r<=0 || r>10){
        printf("Invalid radius: %.2f\n",r);
    }
    if(h<=0 || h>10){
        printf("Invalid height: %.2f\n",h);
    }
    if(r>=0 && r<=10 && h>=0 && h <= 10){
    volume = volCyl(r,h);
    k = k++;
    printf(" Cylinder %d radius %.2f height %.2f volume %.2f\n",k,r,h,volume);
    toth = toth + h;
} }while(r>0 && h>0);
    avgh = toth/k;
    printf("Total Height: %.2f\n",toth);
    printf("Average Height: %.2f\n",avgh);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My specified range has to be 1 to 10 inclusive, without the negative values terminating the program, and no other prompts are allowed

Modify your main function

```
do{
    int ex = scanf("%f%f", &r, &h); //scanf returns int

   if (ex == 0)
    {break;}
    if(r<=0 || r>10){
        printf("Invalid radius: %.2f\n",r);
       continue;
    }
    if(h<=0 || h>10){
        printf("Invalid height: %.2f\n",h);
       continue;
    }
   // hence above conditions failed means you have given desired input
   // need not to check any conditions 
    volume = volCyl(r,h);
    k = k++;
    printf(" Cylinder %d radius %.2f height %.2f volume %.2f\n",k,r,h,volume);
    toth = toth + h;
   }while(r>0 && h>0);

  if(k>0) // check this other wise divide by zero will occur
    {
    avgh = toth/k;
    printf("Total Height: %.2f\n",toth);
    printf("Average Height: %.2f\n",avgh);
    }
```

Comment: My specified range has to be 1 to 10 inclusive, without the negative values terminating the program, and no other prompts are allowed

Comment: do you want to print error when user enters 11 or -1 as inputs. i mean range out of 1-10

Comment: I want to print Invalid radius or Invalid height,if they are out of range, and continue prompting input without a text guiding them, and the loop is only terminated when something non-numeric is entered.

Comment: @user2805620 modified answer accordingly.

Comment: the program still terminates after entering negative values. Its the conditions in the while of the do while that I don't know how to change

Comment: That causes the program to not terminate when something non-numeric is entered, and go into infinite output. Shouldn't the conditions of the while portion be changed?

Comment: change condition inside while  `while(r>0 && h>0); ==> while(1);`

Answer (score 1):

Look at the statement inside your while().  Note that this will keep looping if and only if those conditions result in true.

Comment: I know that, but I don't know how to make it include all the values that are under range, which are negative values and zero inclusive

Answer (score 1):

```
do {
    printf("Enter radius: ")
    scanf("%d", &r);
    printf("Enter height: ")
    scanf("%d", &h);
} while(r<=0 || h<=0);
```

You can use a do-while loop that would keep prompting for the user to re-enter the radius and height is either value is less than or equals to 0.

Hope this helps :)